Firebase "reset password link" issue
I am making something I've done many times in the past, without any problem.
But this time things go wrong for some unknown reason.
In my firebase web app, I have a button for the user to reset her/his password.
When I test this feature and click the link received, only a few seconds after it has been sent, I see this:
Try resetting your password again

Your request to reset your password has expired or the link has already been used

What is going on here ?
Did I miss something ?
I've seen posts where people had similar issues, but that did not lead me to a solution.
In case it can be of some use, this is the kind of link I receive :
https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=someCode_KRABDcef_uzxoFjdCduQl-FAY_lEABCDzKQ&apiKey=APIKEY-N24402012&lang=en
And also the code for the function executed when my button is clicked:
  const firePasswordResetEmail = async (email:string) => {
    try {
      await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth,email);
      alert("Password reset link sent!");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err);
    }
  };

The code I am using seems to conform to what can be seen in this document:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users
Nevertheless I face the problem previously described.
One more relevant piece of information follows below.
I get the same kind of message if I use the web interface at:
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/myproject/authentication/users
to send a password reset mail.
This seems to show that my problem may not be related to some code I am using, but rather to some setting in my project.

I have the same issue, did you solve it?

As far as I remember I did not solve it. I just created a new app (or a new project ?)
